# Second Order Approximation Question

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, taylor-expansion, numerical-calculus

I really don't have any idea how to do this question ? I am already try my best to think but i am still get nothing

Let $f \in C^{3}([a,b])$. Find $\alpha$,$\beta$ and $\gamma$ so that

$$\dfrac{\alpha f(x+3h) + \beta f(x+h) + \gamma f(x)}{h}$$

is second order approximation to $f'(x)$. I.e for any $x \in (a,b)$, There are constants $\delta$ and $C$ so that when $|h|\le \delta $,

$$\bigg | \dfrac{\alpha f(x+3h) + \beta f(x+h) + \gamma f(x)}{h} - f'(x) \bigg | \le Ch^2$$

Can Someone help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

To find a representation accurate to the second order, simply expand the representation   in Taylor series to give:
$$
f'(x)=\dfrac{\alpha}{h}\left[f(x)+3hf'(x)+\dfrac{(3h)^2}{2!}f''(x)\right]
+\dfrac{\beta}{h}\left[f(x)+hf'(x)+\dfrac{h^2}{2!}f''(x)\right]
+\dfrac{\gamma}{h}f(x)+\cdots .$$
Equating coefficients gives
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0,\quad\text{which eliminates }f(x);$$
$$3\,\alpha +\beta  =1,\quad\text{which equates the coefficients of }f'(x);$$
$$\alpha\dfrac{9\,h}{2}+\beta\dfrac{h}{2}=0,\quad\text{which eliminates } f''(x).$$
Solving for $\alpha,\,\beta,\,\gamma,\,$ gives
$$\alpha=-\dfrac{1}{6},\quad\beta=\dfrac{3}{2},\quad\gamma=-\dfrac{4}{3}.$$
These values eliminate the terms in $f''(x)$ and the result is therefore accurate to terms of the second order in $h$, as required.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
since
$f(x+h)
=f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac12h^2f''(x)+O(h^3)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
af(x+uh)+bf(x+vh)+cf(x+wh)
&=a(f(x)+uhf'(x)+\frac12u^2h^2f''(x))\\
&+b(f(x)+vhf'(x)+\frac12vh^2f''(x))\\
&+c(f(x)+whf'(x)+\frac12wh^2f''(x))+O(h^3))\\
&=(a+b+c)f(x)+(ua+vb+wc)hf'(x)+\frac12(au^2+bv^2+cw^2)h^2f''(x)
+O(h^3)\\
\end{array}
$

If you want to get
an approximation for
$f'(x)$
as accurate as possible,
then you want to solve
$a+b+c=0,
au+bv+cw=1,
au^2+bv^2+cw^2
=0
$
for $a, b, c$
in terms of
$u, v, w$
and you will get

$\begin{array}\\
af(x+uh)+bf(x+vh)+cf(x+wh)
&=hf'(x)+O(h^3)\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{af(x+uh)+bf(x+vh)+cf(x+wh)}{h}
&=f'(x)+O(h^2)\\
\end{array}
$

Yours is the case
$u=3, v=1, w=0$.